# Lightswitch - Hiding Columns

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

FindControl seems to only reference the name of the grid, not the column name inside the grid. I can't find any documentation or examples regarding FindControlInCollection either.

I don't have any sophisticated logic to wrap this in at this point. Just need to hide columns. I am using C# and VS Update 2.

Answer (score 2):

Under the Activate event of the screen, use this codeblock:

1. Get an `IControlItemProxy` using the name of the grid.
2. Get the control itself.
3. Access the column by its index and set its visibility dynamically.
4. Add a `using` directive to `System.Windows.Controls`.

.

```
partial void ScreenName_Activated()
{
    IContentItemProxy proxy = this.FindControl("NameOfGrid");

    proxy.ControlAvailable += new EventHandler<ControlAvailableEventArgs>((s1, e1) =>
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)e1.Control;

            dataGrid.Columns[0].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            dataGrid.Columns[1].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bryan's answer contains what you need.

*FindControl* only gets a *proxy* for the control. While there are a few things you can set using it, the only way to get to the **actual** control is to access it through the proxy's *ControlAvailable* handler, which provides a reference to the underlying control in its *ControlAvailableEventArgs* parameter.

Also, as you can see, you don't actually set column visibility via the controls that are used in the grid, you set it using the *DataGrid*'s *Columns* collection directly instead.

Comment: No problem. I'm here to help wherever I can. :-)